# Why should XMLs have structure?

Tags: xml, schema

I have an XML schema that has been published to users. It has a fairly complex structure, but it also has some generic elements that allow us to add other data without breaking the published structure.

Example:

```
<record>
    <song>
        <name>thriller</name>
        <artist>Mike</artist>
        <genericData key="year">1980</genericData>
        <genericData key="duration">03:35</genericData>
    </song>
</record>
```

So here I added two genericData elements for year and duration.

We are being asked to add more data to our structure, and can probably use these genericData elements to meet those needs, but what is the drawback of doing this? I know it doesn't keep a relational model to the data (which is bad), but is there anything else will comeback to bite us? It's got a bad smell to me. I would prefer to add specific elements for the new data, but getting pushback about changing our schema.

Answer (score 1):

The "genericData" design pattern is seen quite often in XML, but in my view it's very rarely the best solution. I think one reason people use it is when they are using data-binding tools such as JAXB: these map the XML to data structures in a language like Java, and languages like Java can't handle the same level of flexibility as XML. Without the constraints of data binding (i.e. if you process the XML using tools designed for the job, like XSLT and XQuery), I would exploit the built-in flexibility of XML (either without a schema, or using wildcards in the schema), perhaps with namespaces to add a level of specification control: so

```
<record>
    <song>
        <name>thriller</name>
        <artist>Mike</artist>
        <m:year xmlns:m="http://me.com/ns">1980</m:year>
        <m:duration xmlns:m="http://me.com/ns">03:35</m:duration>
    </song>
</record>
```

Comment: *Design pattern* is an overused term to make things sound grandiose. A design pattern is not the same as "things people do a lot." Especially in this case when it is a bad idea, as you even note. Also, when people do relax the rules as the OP is considering, it isn't to facilitate data binding to an OO language. It's because they feel the schema is too restrictive for every last use case they want to cover, and to relax is a tantalizing if often shortsighted solution. Finally, binding can happen just fine--say with a `Map` in Java

Comment: Although I was sure tempted to because of the notion that you should relax your business rules to conform to a perceived impedance mismatch with an OO language. Never change your business rules to conform to a technology.

Comment: Both notations (<genericData key="year"> and <m:year>) require the schema to be relaxed or extended to accommodate extensions. Both implement the same business rules. So I think the only case for using the former is if it makes processing easier. I don't advise anyone to use data-binding tools, but some people do, and if you go down that route, you may well find you distort the XML representation (NOT the business rules!) to make them work well.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the only compelling reason to use XML over considerably lighter formats like JSON or YAML is the schema definition and instance validation capability of XML. While there are exceptions like the JSON capabilities of Play Framework, you generally can't enforce a schema on these lighter formats. In fact, that can easily be seen as a plus depending on the use case. That's one of the selling points of "schema-less" NoSQL databases.

If you are relaxing your XML so much that the schema is almost incidental, that might be perfectly legitimate based on your use cases. But if that's so, you've lost the only compelling reason to use XML.

I would suggest making sure your "exceptional" cases of generic data are truly rare. There will be a natural inclination to relax the rules that you must resist. But if after careful consideration you feel a schema is too restrictive, then I would suggest abandoning XML altogether. Just know that you will be shifting the burden to your team to handle the logic that is otherwise available out of the box from XML.

Comment: I disagree strongly. XML was invented to handle semi-structured data, and that's where its strength lies.

Comment: Even if true, your point is irrelevant because "semi-structured data" refers to mixed content, which is not the same thing as what the OP describes. Second, I couched my answer as an opinion. According to the rules of Stack Overflow, a downvote because you "strongly disagree" isn't just petulant; it violates the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: "Semi-structured data" refers more precisely to data that is partially constrained by a schema and partially unconstrained, which is the case here. I do think the advice that XML is only worth using if there is a schema is dangerously misleading, so I would defend my down-vote.

Comment: That is actually factually wrong. When you define a schema, it never "partially" applies to an instance. It applies completely; you just may choose to make certain rules in the schema so lax it is as if they weren't there. That isn't the same thing as "unconstrained." By your logic, a parent who is tough on making the kids do the dishes but lax on letting the kids watch HBO late at night isn't always parenting. That's absurd. As for the downvote, you want to enforce your opinion as fact despite the rules of the community. If you need to prove something, that's fine.